# ModuleNotFound error even pip is already used

Tags: python, connexion

I am a new at Python and I have a roblem with installing one framework.
https://github.com/zalando/connexion
I have already used the command in the terminal '`pip install connexion`'
But still when I try to start a programm I get such error:

```
PS C:\Users\fele\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Uebergabe\pYTHON_BACKEND_2020_03_12> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python.exe" "c:/Users/fele/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/Uebergabe/pYTHON_BACKEND_2020_03_12/test_local/test_local_application_hook.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/fele/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/Uebergabe/pYTHON_BACKEND_2020_03_12/test_local/test_local_application_hook.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cwsm import connexion_manager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cwsm'
```

Cannot anybody give me a suggestion why is it happening?
Thanks in advance

Comment: From the link you mentioned it should be `import connexion`

Answer (score 0):

The github page shows:

```
import connexion
```

So your import is wrong, try using connexion.

Source:
https://github.com/zalando/connexion#running-it

Comment: I have jsut renamed all usages from connexion_manager into connexion but the same problems are existing

Comment: do you have multiple python version? try installing it like python -m pip install connexion, if you use python app.py for running the code